# C# Mapping a Calculated Column with Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-objects

I have Linq class that has StartTime and FinishTime properties.  I'm trying to add a RunTime property to the class which is calculated as FinishTime - StartTime.  My first approach was to add it as an unmapped property and do the calculation in the get():

```
[Table(Name = "Log")]
public partial class Log
{
...
    [Column(Name = "Start_Time", DbType = "DateTime NOT NULL")]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "Finish_Time", DbType = "DateTime NOT NULL")]
    public DateTime FinishTime { get; set; }

    public int RunTime
    {
        get { return ((TimeSpan) (this.FinishTime - this.StartTime)).Seconds; }
        set { this.RunTime = value; }
    }
...
}
```

This worked fine at first, but then when I try to use the column to sort in an OrderBy, I get the following error: "The member 'TestProject.Models.Log.RunTime' has no supported translation to SQL."  This makes sense, since this property is not mapped to a database column, it has no way to sort it in the SQL.

My next approach was to try making it a Column with an "Expression" attribute (which I may not be using correctly):

```
[Column(Expression = "DATEDIFF(ss, Start_Time, Finish_Time) AS RunTime")]
public int RunTime { get; set; }
```

But this results in the error: "Invalid column name 'RunTime'."  Which again make sense, because there is no Column named RunTime to map to.

In the current environment I'm working under, I can't alter the database.  Is there a way to add this property to my class and use it in a sorting query?

Thanks!

Comment: Just an FYI - The setter in your RunTime property is going to cause a StackOverflow exception if you call it.  Better to just have a get accessor, and not set.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I'm still somewhat new to C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the sorting doesn't have to happen on the SQL side, I would assume you could ToList() the Linq / Queryable part (convert things into an actual list on the c# side of the fence) and then OrderBy on the result, according to your original column.

(edit)

Ok, so can you just do the computation in the order by then?

```
IEnumerable<Log> logList = db.Logs.OrderBy(x => x.FinishTime - x.StartTime)
```

I've not tried that before but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Hi Mikeb.  You touched on the root of my problem!  I'm using the data in a paginated table (jqGrid), so the sorting needs to happen on the SQL side to be effective.

Comment: That solution will work with some special case handling. I have my query setup to sort by any column jqGrid feeds it, so I just have to put a special case in my logic to do this and choose OrderBy or OrderByDescending.